# How to split a row into multiple rows between two given dates?

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

How do I split a row with

```
Start Date : 02-OCT-2015
End Date   : 31-DEC-2015
```

into rows below in Oracle?

```
02-OCT-2015 31-OCT-2015
01-NOV-2015 30-NOV-2015
01-DEC-2015 31-DEC-2015
```

Comment: is the format always like this? I mean the start date would always start from 13th character and end date from 35th?

Comment: No, start date and end date is 2 columns, and the below records is also 2 columns

Comment: Are you sure about the second record `01-NOV-2015 - 30-OCT-2015`?

Comment: What would be the desired result of Start Date: `02-OCT-2015`and End Date: `29-DEC-2015`?

Comment: oh sorry it should be 30-NOV-2015 for second row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desired **DATE arithmetic** could be done using following:

- **ADD_MONTHS**
- **LAST_DAY**
- **TRUNC**
- **CONNECT BY** i.e. typical row generator
- **CASE** expression

Let's say you have two dates as **start** and **end** dates, the following query would **split the dates into multiple rows** based on the **MONTHS**.

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS
  2    (SELECT DATE '2015-10-02' Start_Date, DATE '2015-12-25' End_Date FROM DUAL)
  3  -- end of sample_date to mock an actual table
  4  SELECT CASE
  5         WHEN start_date >= TRUNC(add_months(start_date,COLUMN_VALUE - 1),'MM')
  6         THEN
  7            TO_CHAR(start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  8         ELSE
  9            TO_CHAR(TRUNC(add_months(start_date,COLUMN_VALUE - 1),'MM'),'YYYY-MM-DD')
 10         END new_start_date,
 11         CASE
 12         WHEN end_date <= last_day(TRUNC(add_months(start_date,COLUMN_VALUE - 1),'MM'))
 13         THEN
 14            TO_CHAR(end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
 15         ELSE
 16            TO_CHAR(last_day(TRUNC(add_months(start_date,COLUMN_VALUE - 1),'MM')),
 17                    'YYYY-MM-DD')
 18         END new_end_date
 19  FROM sample_data,
 20    TABLE(
 21          CAST(
 22               MULTISET
 23                       (SELECT LEVEL
 24                        FROM dual
 25               CONNECT BY add_months(TRUNC(start_date,'MM'),LEVEL - 1) <= end_date
 26                       ) AS sys.OdciNumberList
 27              )
 28         )
 29  ORDER BY column_value;

NEW_START_DATE NEW_END_DATE
-------------- ------------
2015-10-02     2015-10-31
2015-11-01     2015-11-30
2015-12-01     2015-12-25
```

**How the query works:**

If you should understand how row generation works using **CONNECT BY clause**, the rest is simple **DATE** arithmetic.

- `TRUNC(date, 'MM')` gives the first day of the month, which in your case becomes the start date.
- `ADD_MONTHS(date, value)` adds as many months to the date as specified in the *value*.
- `LAST_DAY` gives the last day of the month, which in your case becomes the end date.

Comment: the start date for first record return is 01-OCT-2015, which is not 02-OCt-2015, and the last record should be same as the end date, if it is 25-DEC-2015 then the last record end date should be 25-DEC-2015. how do I modify the query

Comment: @LamChinFei You just need a **CASE** expression to handle it. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(t.column_one, 1, INSTR(t.column_one, ' ')-1) AS col_one,
SUBSTR(t.column_one, INSTR(t.column_one, ' ')+1) AS col_two
FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

**Alternatively**
You could use regex or the substring function. It won't be super fast on very large datasets, but it'll get the job done. as -

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.column_one, '[^-]+', 1, 1) col_one,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.column_one, '[^-]+', 1, 2) col_two,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.column_one, '[^-]+', 1, 3) col_three,
FROM YOUR_TABLE t;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How does this answer OP's question at all?

Comment: Anyway, when it comes to dates, I always prefer **DATE arithmetic** over **string manipulation**. Faster, reliable, flexible, easy to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

So you've got ranges you want to compare: first range is your period of interest ( 02-OCT-2015 to 31-DEC-2015) the other ranges are the months (01-OCT-2015 to 31-OCT-2015)...yeah I know you only want 02-OCT-2015 because of your data, but let's do one thing at time...we'll get there!

You period of interest goes into the future from today's so your answer will need to look into future.

This is what I do:

STEP 1:
make a list of months, defining the start date and end date of each month:
this can be a table or view. I make views.

```
create view mymonths as 
select 
  add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MONTH'), - rownum + 2) month_start,
  add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MONTH'), - rownum + 3) -1 month_end,
from all_objects -- (or any table or view with enough rows)
where rownum < 13
-- today is 10-NOV-2015. 
-- First row will month_start = 01-NOV-2015, minus 1 (the rownum) month = 01-OCT-2015 + 2 = 01-DEC-2015 and month_end = 31-DEC-2015 (find the next month_start, minus a day) 
-- Next row = 01-NOV-2015 and 30-NOV-2015
-- Next row = 01-OCT-2015 and 31-OCT-2015...for 12 rows down
-- adjust the +3 and < 13 as necessary for the scope of your data
```

now we need to get our data ready to 'join' against our month_starts and month_ends:

If the column data looks like this:
Start Date: 02-OCT-2015 End Date: 31-DEC-2015
Then as suggested in the replies, we can use substr to get the data parts.

Just for the proof of the idea, let's make a little view like this:

```
create view mydata as
select 
   to_date(substr(column,13,11),'dd-MON-yyyy') period_start,
   to_date(substr(column,35,11),'dd-MON-yyyy') period_end
from MYTABLE
```

Now we can 'join' like this:

```
Select
   mydata.period_start, mydata.period_end,
   mymonths.month_start, mymonths.month_end
From
   mytable, mymonths
Where
   -- this is tricky, but work it out: it's right...
   mydata.period_start <= mymonths.month_end 
   and
   mydata.period_end => my_months.month_start
```

-- look at the result and see we're almost there. but you wanted 02-OCT-2015 to 31-OCT-2015, or let's say period_start or month start - whichever is latest and on the end of the month, we'll say period_end or month end, which ever is earlist:

```
Select
   case
     when mydata.period_start > mymonths.month_start
       then mydata.period_start 
     else mymonths.month_start
   end COL1,
   case
     when mydata.period_end < mymonths.month_end
       then mydata.period_end
     else mymonths.month_end
   end COL2
From
   mytable, mymonths
Where
   -- this is tricky, but work it out: it's right...
   mydata.period_start <= mymonths.month_end 
   and
   mydata.period_end => my_months.month_start
```